Amplify gen 2, amplify-authenticator "There is already a signed in user."
I'm using Amplify Gen 2 and have a simple Angular 17 standalone app. When locally I run npx ampx sandbox then ng serve my app, I am able to signup and signin/signout multiple times. However, as soon as I alter the app and it reloads, I am signed out and on trying to sign in am warned There is already a signed in user.

I can access the user pool in AWS for my sandbox and sign the user out:

.. however, this makes no difference. The only way I can get it working again is to delete the sandbox and regenerate it.
There's nothing much going on in app.component:
<amplify-authenticator>
  <ng-template
    amplifySlot="authenticated"
    let-user="user"
    let-signOut="signOut"
  >
  <h1>Hello {{user?.signInDetails?.loginId}}</h1>
    <button (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
    <h2>Welcome, {{ user.username }}!</h2>
  </ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>

Unsure if this is relevant, but in resource.ts the Amplify auth is configued as follows:
export const data = defineData({
  schema,
  authorizationModes: {
    defaultAuthorizationMode: 'userPool',
  },
});

Any ideas at all? Not getting much confidence in Amplify Gen 2 with such a basic blocker so early on...

I ran into this same issue and this is what fixed it for me.
In your app.component.ts you should have a constructor with something like
  constructor(public authenticator: AuthenticatorService) {
    Amplify.configure(YOUR_IMPORTED_CONFIG_FILE);
  }

You also need to add that at that right before defining your component
import YOUR_IMPORTED_CONFIG_FILE from '../your_config_path';

Amplify.configure(YOUR_IMPORTED_CONFIG_FILE);

@Component({
...
})


Thanks Victor the second point you made seems to have done the trick. I already had Amplify.configure... in the constructor, but not preceding @Component. The app now happily reloads after making .ts or .html changes and I remain logged in. Cheers!

Just solved it as follows:
import { AuthError } from 'aws-amplify/auth'     
  
 // add a catch to your function, check the error type by name and handle the error
.catch((error) => {
          if (error instanceof AuthError) {
            if (error.name === 'UserAlreadyAuthenticatedException') {
              // do what ever you want !!!!
            }
          }
        })

